# Unable to use All UITableViews after adding a subview to the UIApplication Window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uiview

Strange issue i'm running into that is honestly really frustrating. I've created a side menu bar for my app that I insert using this function:

```
- (void)insertMenunOnView:(UIView*)view atPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    _menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y,     _menuButton.frame.size.width, _menuButton.frame.size.height);
  [view addSubview:_menuButton];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMenu)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
view.userInteractionEnabled = true;

for (UIButton *button in _buttonList)
{
    [_backgroundMenuView addSubview:button];
}


_backgroundMenuView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width, 0, 150, view.frame.size.height);
_backgroundMenuView.backgroundColor =   [UIColor colorWithRed:0.09 green:0.15 blue:0.18 alpha:0.7f];

[view addSubview:_backgroundMenuView];
}
```

it is implemented here in my `UITableViewController` `viewDidAppear` method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    sideBar.insertMenuOnView(self.view, atPosition: CGPointMake(100, 200))
}
```

If I do this, it renders my `TableView` useless. I can select the cells if I tap rapidly back and forth between multiple cells. After about ten seconds of doing this, the cell being tapped will initiate the appropriate segue.

No I tried this hoping I'd be able to get over this problem by changing the function to

```
 - (void)insertMenunOnView:(UIWindow*)view atPosition:(CGPoint)position
{ //// do stuff
}
```

Guess what!? Now every single `tableView` in my entire app is behaving the same as the first! Takes about thirty to forty taps until the cell finally calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Disable tap gesture on view when side menu is closed and enable it when side menu is open.

At present your tap gesture is overriding tap gesture of table view.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is-

When you call `sideBar.insertMenuOnView(self.view, atPosition: CGPointMake(100, 200))`

this method is called

```
- (void)insertMenunOnView:(UIView*)view atPosition:(CGPoint)position
inside your dismissMenu event handler you should remove gesture recognizer
```

inside above method you are adding a gesture recognizer on the current view, when you are done with this view, then you are dismissing it, but the tap gesture still exists and is added over the current view. Now when you try to select any row of the table the touch is not passed to the table as it is intercepted by the layer above it (which of-course is tap gesture recognizer added over the current view.)

To resolve this issue you should remove the tap gesture recognizer from the current view inside your dismissMenu method. Doing so will pass your touches to the corresponding row of the tableView.